# How to get the returned value in jQuery .post()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I get the returned value?

On click my button invokes:

```
$("#generateNumber").click(function(){
   $.post( "./result.php", function( data ) {
      console.log( data );
      $(".generate_number").html(data);
   });
});
```

my result.php:

```
<?php 
   $a = "returnedValue";
?>
```

but my console log doesn't show me my returnedValue. Why not?

Comment: Echo the `$a` .. `echo $a = "returnedValue";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to dump the value in `result.php`:

```
<?php
    $a = "returnedValue";
    echo $a;
?>
```

The data parameter in the callback you use in [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) contains the *output* of `result.php`.  Your PHP script wasn't outputting anything, though.  Make sure you dump any data you want the AJAX call to read.

If you want to call a specific function in your PHP script, you'll probably need to pass some parameters to `jQuery.post()`..a simple example:

```
$("#generateNumber").click(function(){
    $.post("./result.php", {
        functionName: 'foo'
    }, function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
        // foo
    });
});
```

And in `result.php`:

```
<?php
    function foo() { return "foo"; }
    function bar() { return "bar"; }

    switch($_POST['functionName']) {
        case 'foo': echo foo(); break;
        case 'bar': echo bar(); break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: only echo or return? how i can in .post() url to function?

Comment: I'm not sure @user1638121, can you rephrase that?

Comment: on callback .post i have can get only echo? or maybe function foo(){$a ="str" return $a} if i can have function how to get to function in url $.post( "./result.php/howGetFunction", function( data ) {

Comment: @user1638121 see my update.  You can send any `$_POST` parameters to the PHP script and use that to call different functions for different returns.